# Integrating $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was just wondering that when doing the integral of $\sin^2(x)$ why we can't have the answer as 
$$
\frac13\,\sin^3x\,\frac{1}{\cos x}
$$ I think this problem comes from the fact that calculus in my school is taught merely by rote and so I have very little understanding of integration itself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is what people call the "power rule" which happens to only work for polynomials. If you go back to the definition of integrals and derivatoves, you see why it works and why it won't work for trigonometric function. As other have said, if there's any doubt, you can always check your answer by differentiating it (especially since differentiating is often not too difficult)

Answer (score 2):

Remember: by definition, the answer to 
$$
\int \sin^2 (x)\,dx
$$
should be a function (more precisely the family of functions) whose derivative is $\sin^2(x)$.  You had the "guess" that
$$
\int \sin^2(x)\,dx = \frac 13 \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos(x)} + C
$$
How can we check whether this works?  We could take the derivative and see what we get.  Of course, when we take a derivative, the $C$ goes away, since it's a constant.  For the rest, we get the quotient rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac 13 \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos(x)} \right] = 
\frac 13 \frac{3 \sin^2(x) \cos(x) + \sin^4(x)}{\cos^2(x)}
$$
Does this match the thing we were integrating?  I think it's safe to say that it doesn't.

---

What you were attempting to do is effectively a $u$-substitution, i.e. a "backwards chain rule".  In general, $u$-substitution is more subtle than what you tried here, but what you've done looks a lot like a commonly used "trick". Here's an example where an approach like yours could work:

To calculate $\int (2x + 1)^6\,dx$, we could note that we have "stuff" to the power of $6$, i.e. $u^6$ where $u = 2x + 1$.  We already know that 
$$
\int u^6 du = \frac 17 u^7 + C
$$
so, to account for the chain rule, we might try subbing in $u = 2x+1$ and dividing by $\frac {du}{dx} = 2$.  Indeed, we find that
$$
\int (2x + 1)^6 du = \frac 17 (2x + 1)^7 \cdot \frac 12 + C
$$
is correct!  You might try differentiating to check that this is true.

So what was different here?  In this case, $\frac {du}{dx}$ (the derivative of $u$, i.e. the derivative of the inside function) was a constant, so we didn't need to worry about complications from the quotient rule.  In particular:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac 17 u^7 \cdot \frac 1{(du/dx)} \right] = 
\frac 17 (7u^6 (du/dx))\cdot \frac 1{(du/dx)} = u^6 \frac{du/dx}{du/dx} = u^6 = (2x+1)^6
$$
I hope that problem makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: What do you mean by du/dx being a constant? Would your example not work if say it was 2x^2? And also, if this method is not possible then how when we integrate sin^2xcosx is the answer 1/3sin^3x? Why does this method only work for special functions?

Comment: If $u(x)=2x+1$, then $du/dx=2$. $2$ is not a function of $x$, it's a constant. If $u(x)= \sin(x)$, then $du/dx=\cos(x)$, which isn't a constant. To answer that second question, you need to learn about "$u$-substitution", or "substitution". Try looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in doubt you can always just differentiate the answer you get. In this case the product rule and chain rule imply that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{3}\sin^3x\,\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)
=(\cos x\sin^2x)\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)+\color{blue}{\frac13\,\sin^3x\,\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}\right)}
=\sin^2x+\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x}.
$$
The problem is the term coloured in blue.

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule doesn't work like that in reverse - in fact, if you differentiate your "result" you don't get the same function back.

The way to integrate $\sin^2 x$ is to use the power reduction identity

$$ \sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2} $$

and move from there.